# How to reduce memory consumption in browsers when working with 15K records

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, out-of-memory

I have a react application with .Net Core Api as the Service layer. The current architecture of the application is such that every time an operation is done on one of the rows of data, the entire object representing the UI is set. As a result, the memory increases in proportion  to the number of records. Once a 4GB is reached then the browser throws "Out of Memory" error.
Is there any way I can optimize the existing code to reduce memory consumption or force a quick garbage collection?

```
var calculationResults_n = cloneDeep(calculationResults);
var calAgreements = calculationResults_n.hw.agreements;         
var indices: any = [];

// Filtering the calAgreements based on the ProductNo to send to the service layer 
calculatedAgreements = calAgreements.filter((a:any) => a.boQItem.id == productNo);

// Extracting the index of the calAgreements pertaining to the productNo
calAgreements.forEach(function(value:any,pos: number){
  if(value.boQItem.id == productNo)
  {
    indices.push(pos);
  }
});

//Deleting the calAgreements pertaining to the product so that the updated ones are merged back after receiving the response from the Api.
  for(var index = indices.length-1;index>=0;index--)
  {
    calAgreements.splice(indices[index],1);
  }      

post<ICalculationResult>(
  `Master/${id}/addinputdata`,
  {
    productNo,
    calculatedAgreements        
  },
  (data: ICalculationResult) => {      
    //Merging the updated agreements back to the original calAgreements
    calAgreements.push(...data.hw.agreements);
    calAgreements.sort(comparesrlorder);
    calAgreements.sort(compare);        
    
    setCalculationResults(calculationResults_n);                
    onSuccess && onSuccess();
  //Assigning null so that the variable are no longer reachable so that garbage 
 //collection can pick those up. I'm exactly not sure is this the correct location and way to reclaim the memory 
    calAgreements = null;
    calculatedAgreements = null;
    calculationResults = null;
    calculationResults_n = null;

  },
  successNotification,
  failureNotification
);
```

After performing each operation, the memory increases and once it reaches 4gb then the out of memory error is thrown.
[image: Dev Tools memory tab]

Comment: Hello, one suggestion could be that you use pagination first coupled with lazyload to reduce the quantity of information downloaded to client (and so showing in the browser) and at the same time, make the heavy operation on your backend side so the frontend is more about consulting than operating data. I don't know if it's an option for you but just in case...

Comment: It sounds like using `indexedDB` might be helpful